# Extra padding on Bitmap created from a view

Tags: android, bitmap

I am having an issue where I create a Bitmap from a View by calling `view.getDrawingCache();` The bitmap is almost perfect but when I set the bitmap to an ImageView there is some added "space" or "padding" to the top and bottom of the Bitmap.

Here is how I am capturing the view. The view in question has many different views added on top of it to make a sort of stacked effect.

**Is there a way to set the bounds that the bitmap is capturing? or to remove this padding that is added?**

**What I have found**
It appears as if the extra padding is being added due to the "fill_parent" attributes and the "android:scaleType:fitCenter". When I change the scaleType to fitXY the image no longer has padding. The only problem I have with that is that it stretches the image and does not maintain the aspect ratio required.

```
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
```

Here is the code that I am calling to save the bitmap

```
private void saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage) {
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(this);
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "Pictures" + File.separator + "P"
            + File.separator);

    if (!root.exists()) {
        root.mkdirs();
        Log.e("ROOT", "DIRECTORY DOES NOT EXIST");
    } else {
        Log.e("ROOT", "DIRECTORY EXISTS");
        File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "p_"
                + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L) + ".png");

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory);

            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory));
            this.sendBroadcast(intent);
            Log.e("DIRECTORY", "" + sdImageMainDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        } finally {
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(this, SubmissionActivity.class);
            shareIntent.putExtra("URI", Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory));
            startActivity(shareIntent);
            finish();
        }
        // change activity to something to share the picture

    }

}
```

XML for the layout containing the ImageView

```
        <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewEdit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_solid_dark_holo" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: if there is a padding then get it by calling view.getPadding*() methods

Comment: There is not padding being added to the view. I tried setPadding(0,0,0,0).

Comment: why don't you call ImageView.getDrawable() ?

Comment: The view/layout is a composite of many "views" in which are added programmatically. There is no single drawable.

Comment: so how can one ImageView affect the padding of its parent/sibling views?

Comment: I am creating a bitmap from a FrameLayout. That frame layout is given the height and width of its parent. The ImageView is set in the xml layout, and is given an image taken with the camera. This image is crop to be a perfect square. The extra "padding" is in result to the framelayout being larger than the ImageView size. I cannot seem to figure out how to set the frame layout to wrap content without the bitmap being scaled down as well.

Comment: if you don't set any margins both FrameLayout and ImageView will have the same size, use hierarchyviewer to verify that